# Meteor template helper to check if a document exists

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I want to register a helper that i can use in the templates to check if a document exists.

I check if a document exists like this

```js
var selector = {
    userid: "3R2pKdT3x9PjWLsD8",
};;

var this_exists = Af.find(selector, {limit: 1}).count() > 0;
```

I am trying to register a helper like this

```js
Template.registerHelper('ex', function() {
    var selector = {
        userid: "3R2pKdT3x9PjWLsD8",
    };

    var this_exists = Af.find(selector, {limit: 1}).count() > 0;

    if(this_exists == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

and use it like this in my tempates

```html
{{#if ex}}
    {{> quickForm collection="Af" doc=cdoc id="updateSettings" omitFields="userid" class="settings" type="update" buttonContent="Update Settings"}}
{{else}}
    {{> quickForm collection="Af" doc=this id="updateSettings" omitFields="userid" class="settings" type="insert" buttonContent="Insert Settings"}}
{{/if}}
```

but this does not work. Where am i going wrong?.

Comment: Your code looks reasonable at first glance. Can you specify in which way it "does not work"?

Comment: Turned out it was chrome caching some library i was using for an extended period of time,so,the debug window was debugging the cached version which wasn't the one in use but nonetheless managed to conceal the problem with the library i was using.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't solve your problem, then there might a problem with your pub/sub.

You don't need limit. Instead use `findOne` and you don't need to check the count.

```
var exists = Af.findOne({userId: "3R2pKdT3x9PjWLsD8"}); //be careful with userId here, as it might be userid in your codes. 

If(exists){
    return true;
} //we don't need else block here. Your html if else block will work fine with this.
```

Additionally, if the userId you use is current user's id, you can use Meteor.userId()

```
var exists = Af.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
```